# Adding industry dummies to 2SLS in R

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

for my Master Thesis I want to regress the ESG score on the stock price drop during the pandemic. For OLS this works fine. To check for potential Endogeneity I also conduct a 2SLS regression with the industry average ESG score as instrument. This works fine as long as I leave out the industry dummies. When adding them I get the following error Message:

Warning message:

In pf(w, df[1L], df[2L], lower.tail = FALSE) : NaNs produced

Moreover, the diagnostics for weak instruments and Wu-Hausman also show NaN.

I am aware of the dummy variable trap so not all industries were included.

Does anyone know why I get this error message? Any help is appreciated. Below I will provide my results with and without dummies.

Without dummies:

[image]

With dummies:

[image]

Thank you!

As mentioned in the comments I sould provide the minimum working example. I managed to replicate the warning message with the first 10 rows of my data:

structure(list(NAME = c("A-MARK PRECIOUS METALS", "AAON", "AAR",
"ABBOTT LABORATORIES", "ABBVIE", "ABEONA THERAPEUTICS", "ABERCROMBIE & FITCH A",
"ABIOMED", "ABM INDS.", "ABRAXAS PETROLEUM"), ESG = c(30.93,
46.31, 24.66, 70.67, 79.79, 36.58, 69.13, 25.88, 72.66, 18.88
), LogAssets = c(13.538484837701, 13.0147959839376, 14.5473975668402,
18.0628622893116, 18.8299054426017, 11.9263455151269, 15.0139386185708,
13.9751825387466, 15.1444141253049, 11.9688365085588), Quick = c(0.38,
2.27, 1.69, 1.14, 0.6, 2.26, 1.24, 4, 1.32, 0.1), I_Agri = c(0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), I_Cons = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0), I_Fin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), I_Man = c(0,
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), I_Mining = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1), I_Serv = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), I_Trade = c(1,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), I_Utility = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0), Drop = c(0.107419712070875, 0.277738886944347, 0.791427308882015,
0.297000895255148, 0.31485022307202, 0.75, 0.527002967359051,
0.222692078618225, 0.473209685729006, 0.683189655172414), Leverage = c(0.8177,
0.0178, 0.3993, 0.3623, 0.8679, 0.0169, 0.2659, 0, 0.3257, 1.5458
), ROA = c(0.0622, 0.1926, 0.0065, 0.0726, 0.0542, -0.4324, -0.0259,
0.1888, 0.0095, -0.6467), ESG_A = c(41.9334803921569, 41.6947268673356,
42.0122772277228, 41.6947268673356, 41.6947268673356, 41.6947268673356,
41.9334803921569, 41.6947268673356, 37.5789174311926, 34.9968604651163
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

The code I used:

library(AER)

IV2=ivreg(Drop~ESG+LogAssets+Leverage+ROA+Quick+I_Cons+I_Fin+I_Man+I_Mining+I_Serv+I_Trade+I_Utility | ESG_A+LogAssets+Leverage+ROA+Quick+I_Cons+I_Fin+I_Man+I_Mining+I_Serv+I_Trade+I_Utility, data=mwe)

summary(IV2, diagnostics = TRUE)

Rstudio Version: 2022.2.0.443
Operating system: Windows 10 pro 64 bit

Comment: Can you please share your minimal working example? Otherwise we can only guess what’s wrong

Comment: @1muflon1 Thank you for your answer, as you can see I am new to R and programming in general. I provided the 10 first rows of my data and some addintional info. Hope that helps!